# can't sign in my app after mail confirmation（= response is Completed 401 Unauthorized）/ Rails / devise / devise-token-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing user sign in function with *devise* and *devise-token-auth*.
When I create test user record, and try to sign in, It's not working.

Server（localhost） returnd [Completed 401 Unauthorized].

I checked forrowing points.

- stamped confirmed_at column
- typo（password and email）
- *user.confirmed?* => true

## enviroment

- Docker
- ruby 2.7.2
- rails (6.1.3.1)(API)
- bcrypt (3.1.16)
- devise (4.7.3)
- devise_token_auth (1.1.5)

## files

### devise.rb

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = Rails.application.credentials.config[:smtp_settings][:user_name]
  config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.scoped_views = true
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

### devise_token_auth.rb

```rb
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
  config.token_lifespan = 2.weeks
  config.token_cost = Rails.env.test? ? 4 : 10
  config.headers_names = {:'access-token' => 'access-token',
                         :'client' => 'client',
                         :'expiry' => 'expiry',
                         :'uid' => 'uid',
                         :'token-type' => 'token-type' }
  config.send_confirmation_email = true
  config.default_confirm_success_url = 'https://example.com/login'
  config.default_callbacks = false
end
```

### routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'users', controllers: {
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
    }
    resources :users, only: [:show]

  end
end
```

### application_controller.rb

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

end
```

### user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :rememberable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable, :confirmable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

### migration

```rb
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change

    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Required
      t.string :provider, :null => false, :default => "email"
      t.string :uid, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
      t.boolean  :allow_password_change, :default => false

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email

      ## User Info
      t.string :name
      t.string :nickname
      t.string :image
      t.string :email

      ## Tokens
      t.json :tokens

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, [:uid, :provider],     unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: after email confirmation, did you check `user.confirmed? ` ?

Comment: I did user.confirmed? now, The result is true.

Comment: so you call api `sign in` on tool (e.g. Postman) and it return 401 ? or you login on web page then it's show 401 ?

Comment: I used curl and web page in my browser. Both of them returnd 401.

Comment: i noticed that you use `docker`, did your error appear only on `docker virtual machine` ?